# Is this theory equivalent to Tangled Type Theory?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, new-foundations

Language: Multi-sorted first order logic with equality and membership, where for each natural $n$ we have variables $x_i^n$ of sort $n$, and for each decidable monotonic strictly increasing sequence of naturals $s$ [with 0 in its domain] ,we have binary relation symbols $=^s, \in^s$ with the following syntatical restrictions: the symbol $\in^s$ can only occur between variables of sort $s_n$ on the left to variables of sort $s_{n+1}$ on the right, generally denoted as $x_i^{s(n)} \in^s x_j^{s(n+1)}$ [where $s(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ item in sequence $s$]. On the other hand, the symbol $=^s$ can only occur between variables of the same sort, generally denoted as $x_i^{s(n)} =^s x_j^{s(n)}$.

Notation: for simplicity we'll only write the type of a variable at quantification.

**Axioms:** [Multi-sorted ID axioms for each sequence $s$] +

**Extensionality:** $ \forall x^{s_{n+1}} \, \forall y^{s_{n+1}}: \forall z^{s_n} \, ( z \in^s x \iff z \in^s y ) \implies x=^sy$

**Comprehension:** $\exists x^{s_{n+1}} \forall y^{s_n} (y \in^s x \iff \phi^s(y))$;

where $\phi^s$ only uses $\in^s,=^s$ as predicates, and the sorts of all variables written as items of $s$.

> Is this equivalent to Tangled Type Theory "$\sf TTT$" of Holmes [see: [Holmes p:11](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01406.pdf), [Holmes p:4-5](https://randall-holmes.github.io/Papers/tangled.pdf)]?

In the presentation by Holmes there is seeminly one membership and equality relation, unlike here where there is one per type sequence. I was personally thinking of a proof by compactness since every finite fragment of $\sf TTT$ per sequence $s$ is interpretable here, but I'm not that sure?!

Comment: I don’t follow your description.  Do you really mean the sorts and relations to be indexed by *sequences*, not just by individual naturals or pairs of naturals? And if so, I don’t understand your notation for the sorts of the relations: e.g. taking $s$ as the sequence $(1,2,3,4)$, then in the atomic formula $x \in^{(1,2,3,4)} y$, what sorts should $x$ and $y$ have?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, no the variables are indexed by naturals of course, but the relations ($\in$ and $=$) are indexed after sequences. Now lets take for example $s$ to be the sequence (0,2,4,...) [sequences here are taken to be infinite], then for example you can write $x^{s(0)} \in^s x^{s(1)}$, and this would be $x^0 \in^s x^2$, now this is allowed, but what is not allowed is to have per the above sequence $s$ a formula $x^{s(0)} \in^s x^{s(2)}$ which will be $x^0 \in^s x^4$, this is not allowed because what is on the right is not the successor per that sequence of what is on the left.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, as regards $=^s$, then it can only occur between variables of the same type, so we have generally $x^{s(n)} =^s y^{s(n)}$. regarding your question, the sequence must be infinite, but anyhow the variables can be $x^1 \in^{(1,2,3,4,..) }x^2$ or $x^2 \in^{(1,2,3,4,..)} x^3$ or $x^3 \in^{(1,2,3,4,..)} x^ 4$, etc... but it cannot be $x^1 \in^{(1,2,3,4,..)} x^3$ for example.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, I've re-edited the question to address this point, also I allowed finite sequences as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not.  It is very important, very awful, and quite intended that the membership relation between the same two types is the same in different sequences of types.

Comment: but why this is so?